# Cambiar el tamaño del texto en BottomNavigationBar en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Tengo 2 layouts, el normal en donde tengo mi menu que es este:

Y los iconos y texto se ven asi:

[image: normal]

Ahora cree una carpeta para las layout en large: pero se ven asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el icono si cambio de tamaño, casi no se aprecia porque recorte la imagen, pero el texto no lo puedo alinear como en la imagen 1, intente con margin y padding y no

El layout del menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_calculadora"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_calculator2"
        android:title="@string/menu2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_herramientas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu3"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_donate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_donar"
        android:title="@string/menu4"/>
</menu>
```

Menu en layout normal:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

Menu en layout large:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
            app:itemIconSize="40dp"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el layout ?, considera agregar más información para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte de mejor manera, saludos!

Comment: Listo, pense que se entenderia lo que publique xd